# Make jQuery Mobile not reclaim Smart App Banner's space

Tags: jquery, ios, css, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

As described in the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/), Safari 6+ provides so called [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) by means of a special meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" 
   content="        app-id=myAppStoreID, 
            affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, 
              app-argument=myURL"
>
```

While Smart Banners work fine in general, in a jQuery mobile based app, JQM immediately reclaims the space allocated by the [Smart App Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html):

- Browser starts rendering
- Space for the [Smart App Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) gets allocated, the closing X is visible, but the actual banner still appears blank
- Soon after that, the actual JQM content reclaims the whole screen

In effect, **user won't see the [Smart App Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)**.

**Any ideas, how to make JQM not reclaim the space of the Smart Banner?**

**Update 20140629**

Today, I found the JQuery plugin [jquery.smartbanner](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner). This [plugin](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner) provides similar functionality, works with browsers other than Safari and on Android devices.